# Exception Handling with Expression lambda

Tags: c#, .net, exception, lambda, mvp

My DAL doesn't handle exceptions and it will be propagated up to the calling method in the presenter classes where the exception will be handled.

I'm using a single handler called `ExecutAction(Action action)` so I'm catching exceptions in one place rather than repeating in every method.

At the moment, I'm not logging errors. Just alert the user for an action and try to keep the system alive if possible.

When showing messages to users, Presenters will use a static class called `MessagingService`. (`ShowErrorMessage()`). So that I can customize all massage boxes in one place.

```
        private void Search()
        {
            ExecutAction(() =>
            {
                var info = _DataService.GetByACNo(_model.AccountNumber);

                    if (info != null)
                    {
                        _Model = info ;
                        this.SetViewPropertiesFromModel(_Model, _View);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show ("Bank account not found");
                    }
                });
            }


            private void ExecutAction(Action action)
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                }

                catch (NullReferenceException e) { MessagingService.ShowErrorMessage(e.Message); }
                catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException e) { MessagingService.ShowErrorMessage(e.Message); }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e) { MessagingService.ShowErrorMessage(e.Message); }
            }
        }
```

Should I include general exception handler to this, to be able to handle any unforeseen exceptions?

Also could you show me a better way to handle showing messages than using a static?

Does use of lambda statements in every method call (`ExecutAction(() =>`) degrade code readability?

When showing user messages how to show a custom message like "Check the server connection" etc. first and then if the user wants more information (like StackTrace / technical details) he /she could press a button like `More Info` which is in the MessageBox dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with jeffrey about trying to incorporate IoC for your message service. You could define an abstract base presenter class that has a dependency on an interface for your message service. The base class would be responsible for handling the delegate execution + exception logging.

```
public interface IMessageService
{
    void ShowErrorMessage(Exception e);
}

public abstract class PresenterBase
{
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;

    public PresenterBase(IMessageService messageService)
    {
        this._messageService = messageService;
    }

    protected void ExecuteAction(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }

        catch (Exception e) { this._messageService.ShowErrorMessage(e); }
    }
}

public class SearchPresenter: PresenterBase
{
    public SearchPresenter(IMessageService messageService)
        : base(messageService)
    {
    }

    public void Search()
    {
        this.ExecuteAction(() =>
        {
            //perform search action
        });
    }
}
```

Regarding your question about catching all exeptions. Unless you are doing something special for specific types of exceptions, I would suggest just handling all the same. The example I provided passes the exception to the message service so that the formatting specifics can be handled by your message service.

If you have not yet incorporated any sort of IoC container, you can always start by using the interface injection and then passing the instance explicitly from the child class constructor.

```
public class SearchPresenter: PresenterBase
{
    public SearchPresenter()
        : base(new SomeMessageService())
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

This is at least removes the static dependency and is not too dificult to swap out later if you ever introduce an IoC container.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is good enough for your work. Wrapping logics by `ExecuteAction` is an acceptable way to me. As another option, I might use AOP for centralized exception handling in practice.

Also, I might use a `MessagingService` resolved from dependency injection container rather than a static one.

Regarding how to display the error, that's totally depend on your business purpose. For example, you could simply log the error and tell the user "something's wrong", or show them the complete stacktrace including the environment information so they could simply copy & paste in the email.

Comment: Regarding the messaging, I'm thinking to show both messages (user and technical) in the same message box. Only if the user is an admin, then he / she could press `More Info` button which in the same message box. then it'll display the technical details too next to the earlier one ! Is it an acceptable way?

Comment: Well, it's OK for me, but I think you should still confirm with the requirement or the support people.